# Java does not use all available CPUs

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8, fork-join

I have a long running calculation which I need to carry out for a long list of inputs. The calculations are independent, so I would like to distribute them to several CPUs. I am using Java 8.

The skeleton of the code looks like this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

MyService myService = new MyService(executorService);

List<MyResult> results =
            myInputList.stream()
                     .map(myService::getResultFuture)
                     .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

executorService.shutdown();
```

The main function responsible the calculation looks like this:

```
CompletableFuture<MyResult> getResultFuture(MyInput input) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> longCalc(input), executor)))
}
```

The long running calculation is stateless and does not do any IO.

I would expect this code to use all available CPUs, but it does not happen. For example, on a machine with 72 CPUs and `numThreads=72` (or even eg. `numThreads=500`), cpu usage is at most 500-1000%, as shown by htop:

[image: htop]

According to the thread dump, many of the calculation threads are waiting, ie.:

```
"pool-1-thread-34" #55 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe858597890 nid=0xd66 waiting on condition [0x00007fe7f9cdd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000381815f20> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

All calculation threads were waiting for the same lock. At the time of the dump, only 5 calculation threads were RUNNABLE, the rest were WAITING.

What can be the reason for the locks and why do I not manage to use all cpus?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are submitting jobs and calling `join()` right afterwards, waiting for the completion of the asynchronous job.

Stream intermediate steps are executed element-wise, which means that the intermediate step `.map(CompletableFuture::join)` runs on one element at a time (even worse as it's a sequential stream), without making sure all elements have gone through the submission step. This causes the thread to block while waiting for the completion of each single calculation.

You have to enforce a submission of all jobs before starting to call `join()` on them:

```
List<MyResult> results =
    myInputList.stream()
               .map(myService::getResultFuture)
               .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
               .map(CompletableFuture::join)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you can express whatever you want to do with the `results` list as an action to be invoked when everything is done, you can implement the operation in a way that does not block threads with `join()`:

```
List<CompletableFuture<MyResult>> futures = myInputList.stream()
    .map(myService::getResultFuture)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new))
    .thenRun(() -> {
        List<MyResult> results = futures.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        // perform action with results
    });
```

It still calls `join()` to retrieve the result, but at this point, all futures have been completed so the caller won’t get blocked.

Comment: `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` **does** submit the job to the executor service before it returns. If this improves parallelism, can you or the OP perhaps explain what makes the difference?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele It does submit to the executor service, but as Holger explains, it immediately waits for completion of the single tasks submitted. It's the same thing as running on a single thread. Holger's fix first submits all tasks to the executor service, then when all tasks are submitted, waits on all futures returned.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right and the solution works perfectly. My only question is, what explains that there were still usually around 5-10 cpus used before the fix?

Comment: Every time you submit a job to the pool, an arbitrary worker thread may pick it up and even the thread to CPU mapping is not fixed (that’s system specific). So when you repeatedly do `submit` followed by immediate `join`, you’re generating 100% work for a CPU core (plus some overhead), but it doesn’t have to end up with one core at 100% load, but may get distributed over multiple cores having less than 100%. Now, a CPU isn’t actually “80% busy”. It’s either busy or idle, so the monitoring tool has to record that state over a time frame to calculate a percentage. This makes snapshots imprecise.